# Can I do a http post and then redirect?

Tags: asp.net, http, httprequest, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to understand this properly.

I have a simple web form which, in the page load, I have a bit of code that creates a `HttpWebRequest` object. This then performs a Http POST passing some info in the body.

The response passes back a 302 redirect just fine. How would I redirect to the location page from the response in the page load? If I did a `Response.Redirect` would that being doing a HTTP GET again?

In addition, some of the info I pass in the post body will determine if I can even access the page that it wants to redirect.  What's stopping someone getting the location URL and just pasting that in the browser and essentially doing a HTTP GET as well?

It is a little confusing and I may not be grasping it correctly and would love some insight.

Comment: `..doing a HTTP GET as well` - Depending on the full details of what seems to be some authorization flow, _typically_ there would be some "token" being passed around that would have some control (expiration perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

> How would I redirect to the location page from the response in the page load?

Sow the code that makes the request. You'll have to read the redirect location from the response and see [MSDN: How to: Redirect Users to Another Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> If I did a response.redirect would that being doing a get again?

Yes.

> Whats stopping someone getting the location URL and just pasting that in the browser and essentially doing a get as well?

If you mean the "location" header from the 302 response to the POST you make in your Page_Load: your server will perform this POST request, not the client's browser. So they won't see this request or the URL it points to.

However, if you redirect them to the location the 302 response to the POST is pointing to, then their browser will go there anyway.